# the closest Sunday before given date with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I need to know the date for last Sunday for given date in **php** & **javascript**

Let's have a function give_me_last_Sunday

```
give_me_last_Sunday('20110517') is 20110515
give_me_last_Sunday('20110604') is 20110529
```

The full backup is done on Sundays = weekly. If I want to restore daily backup I need full (weekly) and daily backup. I need to copy backup files before restoring to temp directory so I restoring daily backup I need to know what weekly backup file I need to copy along the daily file.

My thought was to get Julian representation (or something similar) for the given date and then subtract 1 and check if it is Sunday ... Not sure if this is the best idea and how to convert given date into something I can subtract.

Comment: 'Last Sunday' means 'the closest Sunday on or before given date'?  Or 'the closest Sunday before given date'?

Comment: @Jonathan: the closest Sunday before given date. I provided examples so it is very clear ...

Comment: It may be clear to you - it was not clear to me.  Since 2011-05-17 is a Tuesday, and 2011-05-16 is a Monday, it is not clear that the sample data satisfies the question. Similarly, 2011-06-04 is a Saturday (and 2011-05-29 is a Sunday), so your sample data does not show what you require when the given date is a Sunday.

Comment: you're right.Thank you for pointing it out....fixed

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on Thomas' effort, and provided the input string is exactly the format you specified, then:

```
function lastSunday(d) {
  var d = d.replace(/(^\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2}$)/,'$1/$2/$3');
  d = new Date(d);
  d.setDate(d.getDate() - d.getDay());
  return d;
}
```

#### Edit

If I were to write that now, I'd not depend on the Date object parsing the string but do it myself:

```
function lastSunday(s) {
  var d = new Date(s.substring(0,4), s.substring(4,6) - 1, s.substring(6));
  d.setDate(d.getDate() - d.getDay());
  return d;
}
```

While the format yyyy/mm/dd is parsed correctly by all browsers I've tested, I think it's more robust to stick to basic methods. Particularly when they are likely more efficient.

Comment: Rob: works! any chance you can explain this function to me? Especially the very last part. I cannot grasp why it gives me last Sunday :-)

Comment: The first part uses a regular expression to convert 20110504 to 2011/05/04 which is an ISO8601 format that the javascript Date object can parse by default. That string is converted to a date object using `new Date()`. *setDate(int)* sets the date of a date object, *int* can be negative so that the date is set prior to the current month. *getDate()* returns the current date, *getDay()* returns the current day number of the week, which is zero for Sunday. So subtracting the day number from the date always gives Sunday. If the date goes negative, the Date object adjusts it to the previous month.

Comment: any idea why `d.getMonth()` returns `4` whilst `d` returns `May` for `20110516`?

Comment: because getMonth() returns the values from 0-11

Comment: @RobG, great explanation, and a great solution.  Date functions in Javascript are extremely frustrating and confusing, with UTC, getDate, setDate, getDay... all the terms are too similar and do similar things.  Is there a succinct summary that you would recommend?  You seem to intuitively understand this stuff.

Comment: @SableFoste—Date objects are fairly simple, they are based on a UTC time value that is milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00Z. They have a read–only timezone offset that is used to calculate local values for getHours, getMonth, toString, etc. The UTC methods return UTC values and getTime returns the UTC time value. Finally, Date.UTC can be used to turn a UTC date into a Date object. Does that help?

Comment: @RobG, I guess it takes a certain amount of playing to anticipate the proper output (`console.log` is my friend :D ).  Thank you for the response; I was wondering more if you had a web link reference that you preferred.

Comment: **The** best reference is the standard: [ECMA-262 §5.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9). There's also JR Stockton's [JavaScript Date and Time Introduction](http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/js-dates.htm), which is technically excellent but difficult to absorb, and the [MDN wiki](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Being a public wiki, it's more documentation of observed behaviour by random individuals (so technically lacking). At least it's comprehendable. Whatever you read, compare it with what ECMA-262 actually says. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Ok so this is for JavaScript only. You have an input that you need to extract the month, date, and year from. The following is just partly an answer then on how to get the date:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myDate=new Date();
myDate.setFullYear(2011,4,16)

var a = myDate.getDate();
var t = myDate.getDay();
var r = a - t;
document.write("The date last Sunday was "  + r);

</script>
```

So the setFullYear function sets the myDate to the date specified where the first four digits is the year, the next are is the month (0= Jan, 1= Feb.,...). The last one is the actually date. Then the above code gives you the date of the Sunday before that. I am guessing that you can add more code to get the month (use getMonth() method). Here are a few links that might be helpful

- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp
- [http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setFullYear.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp)
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getMonth.asp

(You can probably find the other functions that you need)

I hope this helps a bit even though it is not a complete answer.

Comment: @Thomas, where do I specify the given date?

Comment: @Radek: Sorry, I misread your question. You wanted to have an input in date form. Let me just think about that ...

Comment: @Radek: I see now. You still need to figure out what day (Monday , ...) a specific date corresponds to. And how do we do that ...

Comment: hmmm, I am testing your code and it gives me last Sunday from today. So I guess I can use your code with some modification. But I do not understand the code at all :-)

Comment: @Radek: Yes, my code isn't what you actually want. But it does "some of it". I think you just use the getDay method.

Comment: the variable d is assigned with today's date if we can pass it any date would it work?

Comment: This looks more like it:

var myDate=new Date();
myDate.setFullYear(2011,4,16)

var a = myDate.getDate();
var t = myDate.getDay();
var r = a - t;
document.write("The date last Sunday was "  + r);

Comment: not sure about `myDate.setFullYear(2011,4,16);` it seems to me that this part doesn't work. If I print myDate I get `Mon May 16 2011 09:38:53 GMT+1000 (EST)`

Comment: @Thomas. Thank you for your help. Rob gave you credit in his answer. His code works nicely for me.

Comment: @Radek: I am glad that you found a way. And sorry again for being confused about it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Yup and strtotime has been ported to JS for eg http://phpjs.org/functions/strtotime:554 here.

Answer (score 0):

final code (big thanks to @Thomas & @Rob)

```
function lastSunday(d) {
  var d = d.replace(/(^\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2}$)/,'$1/$2/$3');

  d = new Date(d);
  d.setDate(d.getDate() - d.getDay());

  year = d.getFullYear()+'';
  month = d.getMonth()+1+'';
  day = d.getDate()+'';
  if ( month.length == 1 ) month = "0" + month; // Add leading zeros to month and date if required
  if ( day.length == 1 ) day = "0" + day;  

  return year+month+day;
}
```