# Given a certain date (DD/MM/YYYY) return the start + end of week

Tags: javascript, date

I've got some dates I need to provide as args to my calendar

Say my holidays are

Start : 15/01/2015 ,
End:    25/01/2015

I need a way in which to pragmatically find the sunday before the start date (In this case 10/01/2015), Aswell as the week ending date which comes after my holidays end (31/02/2015) .

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: You should use the getDay() method: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp
Note that sunday is 0, so you just need to compare the current day in a iteration or something like.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144940/get-next-week-start-and-end-using-jquery-and-moment-js

Comment: @Dillenger This isn't very helpful for me sorry, this is assuming you are using todays date, I am not I would like to provide custom dates

Comment: @Adam thanks for the link, If possible however I would like to do this in vanilla, it's for a work system which I don't think needs more libraries

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024328/the-closest-sunday-before-given-date-with-javascript

Comment: @does_not_compute "This isn't very helpful"? You can't replace `new Date()` with your custom date? Please don't expect a copy-paste answer to a question like this. Just use your brain, and apply the given tips.

Comment: @Teemu I had no idea I could do that, I've come here for help stop being so rude.

if dillenger had said I can provide my own date as an argument when instantiating a date object I would have known what to do, but he didn't.. I'm pretty amazed someone with as many points on this site believes that 1st answer to be a clear solution to my question when I have little experience working with JS dates.

Comment: @Undefined_variable Perfect exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much :D

Comment: Reading [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) might help?

Comment: @Teemu thanks thats actually useful. I use w3schools a lot of time for docs but they miss a lot of the essentials clearly I can tell after reading that

Comment: Well, you're not the only person who has found [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/) being not the best resource for learning. My comment above was not intended to be rude, I'm sorry if you've taken it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var startDate = new Date("01/15/2015");
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - startDate.getDay()-1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Exactly what I was after

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var firstDayOfHolidays = new Date(); // You can set the date you want
var lastDayOfHolidays = new Date(); // You can set the date you want

var previousSunday = new Date(firstDayOfHolidays.getFullYear(), 
                              firstDayOfHolidays.getMonth(),         
                              firstDayOfHolidays.getDate() - firstDayOfHolidays.getDay());

var nextSunday = new Date(lastDayOfHolidays.getFullYear(), 
                          lastDayOfHolidays.getMonth(),
                          lastDayOfHolidays.getDate() - lastDayOfHolidays.getDay()+7);
alert( previousSunday );
alert( nextSunday );
```