# How to get UNIX time with moment.js with particular string format "last ..."?

Tags: angularjs, unix, momentjs, angular-moment

In PHP, it's possible to say:

```
$unixTimeOfLastSunday = strtotime("last Sunday");
```

Which would equate to something like this: `1465714800`

How would one accomplish the same thing in either Javascript or AngularJS?

**EDIT -** I am now using `moment.js` as an angular library. Here's my controller:

```
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'moment', function ($scope, moment) {

    moment.updateLocale('en', {
        meridiem: {
            am: 'am',
            AM: 'AM',
            pm: 'pm',
            PM: 'PM'
        }
    });

    var sunday = moment().calendar("Last Sunday at 12:00 AM");
    var sundayUnix = moment(sunday).unix();
    console.log(sundayUnix);

});
```

But for some reason, the console always spits out today, and not Sunday.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [the closest Sunday before given date with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024328/the-closest-sunday-before-given-date-with-javascript)

Comment: See the [momentjs documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/). Search for "Unix Epoch", there are examples of how to parse from the number and how to get the number from a moment instance.

Comment: @Igor, I tried a solution, but have failed. I edited my question accordingly, can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). You can combine  http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/ and http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/.

**Edit**: So apparently, momentjs is really awesome and anything is possible - and easy, if you explore the rich API. The answer is simply `moment().day("Sunday").unix()`.

Beautiful if you ask me! :) Relevant [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/).

Comment: Can you please elaborate using a code example? I've been at this all day! I can't seem to find the right way to do the calendar so that whatever day it is (mon-sat) it will always give me "last sunday"

Answer (score 0):

**Using `moment.js`:** https://momentjs.com/

In order to get the Sunday in the week prior, this works:

```
var sunday = moment().day(-7);
```

In order to get the Sunday of the current week:

```
var sunday = moment().day(0);
```

To get this day's Unix time at midnight:

```
var sundayMidnight = moment().day(0).startOf('day').unix();
```